# In C++, when a class is not in the same file as the main routine, does the runtime get much slower?

Tags: c++

I use a class called Year to return a very distant from now year. In case 1. I keep the class together with the main routine in the same file called YearAllTogether.cpp and in case 2. I place the class in a Year.cpp along with its corresponding header, Year.h. When I run the 1st case where everything is together (YearAllTogether.cpp), I get a runtime of 7.4e-05 sec whereas when I run the code where the class is in its own file and header, the runtime gets up to a huge 1.84526 sec. What is happening/what am I missing here? To get some measurable runtime, I use a for-loop to use the class 10^9 times. I post below the code for the two cases:

Case 1. Class and main in the same .cpp file, that is, YearAllTogether.cpp.

I compile with g++ -Wall -O3 YearAllTogether.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

class Year
{
private:
    long m_nYear;

    Year() { };

public:
    Year(long nYear);

    void SetYear(long nYear);

    long GetYear(){return m_nYear;};
};

Year::Year(long nYear)
{
    SetYear(nYear);
};

void Year::SetYear(long nYear)
{
    m_nYear = nYear;
};


int main ()
{

  struct timeval tvalBefore, tvalAfter;
  gettimeofday (&tvalBefore, NULL);

  Year long_after(0);

  for (long i=1; i<=1000000000; i++)
    {
      Year temp_year(i);
      long_after = temp_year;
    }

  cout<<long_after.GetYear()<<"\n";

  gettimeofday (&tvalAfter, NULL);
  double runtime = (((tvalAfter.tv_sec - tvalBefore.tv_sec)*1000000L
                     +tvalAfter.tv_usec) - tvalBefore.tv_usec)/1000000.;
  cout << "TIME                          "<<runtime<<" sec"<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Case 2. Class and main in different files, here I compile with                                 g++ -Wall -O3 Year.cpp YearMain.cpp

Year.h

```
#ifndef YEAR_H
#define YEAR_H

class Year
{
private:
    long m_nYear;

    Year() { };

public:
    Year(long nYear);

    void SetYear(long nYear);

    long GetYear(){return m_nYear;};
};

#endif
```

Year.cpp

```
#include "Year.h"

using namespace std;

Year::Year(long nYear)
{
    SetYear(nYear);
};

void Year::SetYear(long nYear)
{
    m_nYear = nYear;
};
```

and YearMain.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "Year.h"

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

  struct timeval tvalBefore, tvalAfter;
  gettimeofday (&tvalBefore, NULL);

  Year long_after(0);

  for (long i=1; i<=1000000000; i++)
    {
      Year temp_year(i);
      long_after = temp_year;
    }

  cout<<long_after.GetYear()<<"\n";

  gettimeofday (&tvalAfter, NULL);
  double runtime = (((tvalAfter.tv_sec - tvalBefore.tv_sec)*1000000L
                     +tvalAfter.tv_usec) - tvalBefore.tv_usec)/1000000.;
  cout << "TIME                          "<<runtime<<" sec"<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

I have tested things on a more realistic ground as I wrote in the comments and this is what I found:

If we have only two classes, e.g. one to generate random numbers and another to generate 2-d vectors (which also adds and subtracts vectors) and we use in our main() a for-loop to generate in each iteration few 2-d vectors and add/subtract/operate on them somehow, then all-classes-in-one-file gives a better runtime by a 5-10%, depending on the operations on the vectors and their number within the for-loop.

However, if what we do in our main() is not simply iterating over a for-loop and we have more classes, say of order 5, with more complex operations, then the approach every-class-in-its-own-file has no significantly longer runtime compared to all-classes-in-one-file!

Many thanks for the insight!

Comment: "In C++, when a class is not in the same file as the main routine, does the runtime gets much slower?" - No!! Why would it.

Comment: I totally agree with you but still I don't know what I am missing in the example above. The runtime in the second case is much much longer.

Comment: try enabling `-flto`.

Comment: @gcfora Please elaborate on reasons, why you think there could be a performance difference. I can't see any?!?

Comment: @MitchWheat: it's quite possible that the entire computation is done statically when the compiler can see the whole code...

Comment: @Kerrek SB: really? including unrolling the loop? I see how this might make it a 'bit' faster (excluding ambient OS variations), but not much faster.

Comment: @MitchWheat: When you see the computation, you don't need to unroll the loop. You just replace it with the final result (in this case the final *value* even). Check the machine code.

Comment: Good point. @Kerrek SB is likely correct. I suggest you inspect the assembly code produced by both (or post it here).

Comment: Thank you guys! How do I get the assembly code so that I can post it here?

Comment: yngum, I have tried with g++ -Wall -O3 -flto Year.cpp YearMain.cpp but I got these errors:                                        cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-flto"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-flto"

Comment: To improve your performance, use the keywords "const", "private" and "static" more.  For example, your `GetYear` method should have "const" appended to it since it doesn't change any of the class members.  The `SetYear` function could be placed into the header file, similar to the `GetYear` function.  This changes should minimize any performance loss due to redistribution of functions to separate translation units.

Comment: gcfora, your command works for my `gcc-4.8`, you probably have an ancient version.

Comment: @gcfora: This a mildly interesting question, but you shouldn't get terribly worked up about it. Your code is highly contrived, and real code (code that isn't blatantly a waste of time) doesn't usually offer such vast optimization opportunities. After all, if your code has no effects, why would you write it. In real code, things like inlining, loop unrolling and devirtualization are probably more important and effective.

Answer (score 4):

Compiler optimizations can have impressive effects. Loop optimizations are among the most profitable ones, and what you're seeing is a standard optimization: if the compiler can prove that a loop has no other effects and performs only a tractable action, it can remove the loop entirely and replace it just by the resulting final state.

Clearly, in your case, inclusion of the class member definitions allows the compiler to see that there is no side effect in the `Year` constructor aand copy-assignment operator, so the only effect of the loop is to set the final value.

For a simpler demonstration, consider this code:

```
int main()
{
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) { val += i; }
    return val;
}
```

Let's look at mildly optimized code:

```
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        mov     eax, 55
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

As you can see, the compiler has figured out what the loop does.

Comment: +1 for showing the optimization is not really related to the dispersion of functions across translation units.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Well, indirectly. The optimization isn't about the cost of function calls, that's for sure. What matters is the provable lack of side effects of the loop operations...

Answer (score 0):

In the separate-compilation case, the compiler must produce object code for the Year class methods and later link it against main().  This means the function calls will be done the normal way.  But if you expose all the code in a single translation unit and compile it at once, the compiler (or, well, the optimizer) can see everything and build it for faster performance.  Specifically, your constructor can be inlined if the compiler sees all the code, otherwise not.  It's even possible that the compiler will completely eliminate the loop or at least the copies within it when it can see all your code.

If you want the same high performance with separate files, simply #include "Year.cpp" in your main file  and compile just that one file.  This will have the same effect (single translation unit) without cluttering up your main file.  To do this "for real" you'd want to define all the methods as `inline` to avoid linker errors, though in a single-file program this won't matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The thing is that this is an example of what I am facing for a Monte Carlo integration in which I will need maybe 5-6 classes which will be used millions of times in each run. So I was hoping to avoid the #include .cpp solution but if that is not possible, it will do.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the distribution of functions to more than one file, has no impact on performance.

However, there are a few cases of optimization where the compiler can better optimize performance when all the functions are in the same module.  One example is *inline*.

**Automatic Inlining**
If the compiler can find the implementation of a function in the same file (translation unit) as the calling function, the compiler may be able to *inline* the function.  To *inline* means to replace the function call with the actual code of the called function.  The compiler may invoke this on some of the more advanced optimization settings.  This would be performed by the compiler.

One method around this is to declare and define small functions as inline in the header file.  This is a suggestion to the compiler to paste the code in from the header file.

**Linker Optimization**
Some linker options allow for optimizations across translation units.  These optimizations may counter any effects of distributing code among different files.

**Negligible Loss**
In most applications, the loss of performance is negligible.  In most cases, functions are distributed to improve development and maintenance times, which are more costly than performance bottlenecks.

I suggest not to worry about any performance loss by distributing functions.  **After** your program works correctly and robustly, then worry about performance.  When you need to improve performance **optimize first** to find where the bottlenecks are and concentrate your performance optimizations in those areas.  Most of them will not be related to function distribution.

Comment: Would you have any suggestion on where to search for linker optimization? I am not really optimizing my code per se, I've just redistributed the classes I use in their own files and I saw that the running time went up by a factor of 3. And this for the case that still the classes are relatively small, I have to implement new  functions to them and I am afraid that the delaying factor will not stay to 3!

Comment: Yes, your compiler documentation!  Search the web for "linker optimization " followed by your compiler or linker name.

Comment: See Kerrek SB's answer above.  In once case, your loop may be eliminated by either returning the final result or replaced by a math operation (for example a loop of repetitive additions can be replace by a multiplication).  Since the compiler can't see all the functions, it leaves the loop in.  Thus the reason for the high difference in performance:  your loop is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everybody! I see the point in this example. I will test again my code and write back. In what I am really doing, one of the classes that needs to be used millions of times, returns an array  (<vector>) containing 20 to 30 three dimensional unit vectors generated randomly. I will see how much the runtime is delayed if this class is in a separate .cpp file and post back.

Answer (score -1):

Cross-procedure optimizations, the most important of which is inlining, require the optimizer to see into all related procedures at the same time.  Luckily, the sweet spot for inlining generally corresponds to very short functions that don't deserve to be placed into a separate implementation file.

For your example, I would recommend a header-only implementation:

```
#ifndef YEAR_H
#define YEAR_H
class Year
{
private:
    long m_nYear;

    Year(void) : m_nYear(-1) {}

public:
    Year(long nYear) : m_nYear(nYear) {}

    void SetYear(long nYear) { m_nYear = nYear; }
    long GetYear(void) { return m_nYear; }
};
#endif
```

Now you won't have that `#include "some.cpp"` code smell.

I've also removed useless semicolons and demonstrated the right way to initialize class subobjects, using the initializer list.

In most cases, prefer to put function bodies inside the class definition.  A function that feels too long to put in the header file, is also unlikely to be inlined.

The downside is that you lose benefits of compile firewalling, as may be provided by pimpl.  But you can't get aggressive cross-procedure optimization and minimal compile surface at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the example above! I noticed some semicolons that shouldn't be there in my example, and indeed what you have posted looks much neater! As I wrote to a comment further down the page, this example was oversimplifying, just to show the issue. I am testing now one real class from my code and I will post the results here.